# Wear OS 4.0: Watchface corrupted after App close

Tags: wear-os

So my app has a watchface and some activities. I start my Mainactivity after i tap on the watchface and if the user is done what he wanted to do, the Mainactivity is closed by calling finish()
After that the watchface is visible again.

This all works great on Wear OS 3 (or 3.5) on the Galaxy Watch 4 and 5.
But after updating to Wear OS 4 the watchface is completely wrong. the background is completely white and since all my graphics except for the second-hand is white, nothing is shown.

I looked into the renderer method and everything is called fine. Looked up the WatchFaceKotlin example from google, it is basically the same as my watchface.

I know, Wear OS 4 is only out for 2 weeks but maybe someone has a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it myself. my watchface did not call canvas.drawColor(...) which was not a problem on wear os 3.5 - it was always automatically black. now the canvas most of the time keeps the background color of the app which was started (sometimes not, which is funny...)